# How to apply group By on multiple table in linq

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I have query in linq like this

```
   var result = from item1 in context.ServicePriceInsertData
                                 join item2 in context.GroupMasterInsert
                                 on item1.G_Id equals item2.Group_Id
                                 join item3 in context.EmployeeServices
                                 on item1.Service_Id equals item3.E_ServiceId

                                 into dept
                                 from item4 in dept.DefaultIfEmpty()

                                 select new 
                                 {

                                     Service_Name = item1.S_Description,
                                     Group_Name = item2.Group_Name,
                                     ServiceId = item4.E_Id == null ? 1 : item4.E_Id

                                 };
```

Now i need to count ServiceId  with group by Service and   Group_Name.
Please help  me?

Comment: Show your class model. Joins should be done with navigation properties. We don't know which you have. Also: what did you try?

Comment: I have edit my query.Have a look may be this help you to understand the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is not tested but please try.. i hope it could helps you and get some idea on how to Group by and Count in linq. For more details [linq + C# + group by + count](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/296196/linq-plus-Csharp-plus-group-by-plus-count)

```
        var result = from item1 in context.ServicePriceInsertData
                     join item2 in context.GroupMasterInsert on item1.G_Id equals item2.Group_Id
                     join item3 in context.EmployeeServices on item1.Service_Id equals item3.E_ServiceId
                     group new {  item1.S_Description, item2.Group_Name, item1 } by new { item.S_Description } into g

                     select new
                     {

                         Service_Name = g.Key.S_Description,
                         Group_Name = g.Key.Group_Name,
                         Counted =  (int?)g.Count()
                     };
```